# asp.net core 3.1 dependency injection unable to resolve interface with multiple implementation

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1

i am new to dependency injection.

I am using asp.net core 3.1 application. I want to use single interface with multiple implementation. i used to following code in `startup -> configureservices()`

```
AddTransient<Func<FilterTypeConstants, ICanRetrieveForms>>(x => key =>
                {
                    switch (key)
                    {
                        case FilterTypeConstants.A:
                            return new RetrieverA(x.GetService<Repository>());
                        case FilterTypeConstants.B:
                            return new RetrieverB(x.GetService<Repository>());
                        default:
                            return null;
                    }
                })
```

And in the contoller i am using like:

```
private readonly ICanRetrieveForms _retriever;

public ContollerA(Func<FilterTypeConstants, ICanRetrieveLearnerFormAssignments> serviceResolver) {
    _retriever = serviceResolver(FilterTypeConstants.B)
}
```

but getting error saying ' Unable to resolve service of type ICanRetrieveForms....'

Can anyone help me how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: `ICanRetrieveLearnerFormAssignments != ICanRetrieveForms` is that a typo?

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear.

Comment: x.GetService<Repository>() might be causing problems